# Checking GET variables in the URL with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

If I have a url https://stackoverflow.com/?variable=12345 how can I check if there is a GET parameter in the URL and what it is equals to in JS or jQuery?

For example in PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['variable']))
   $variable = $_GET['variable'];
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are comparing serverside code with client side code.

Comment: You can refer this question url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273788/get-url-variables-from-url-to-form-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_var(var_name){
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == var_name){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

And to use:

```
var get_variable = get_var("variable");
if (get_variable !== '') {

  // Variable exists

}
```