# Putting URL variables into HTML form with JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to pass variables in the URL like this to fill a HTML and Liquid form and submit it once it's populated:

http://www.example.com/login?customer_email=admin@website.com&customer_password=123456

The closest thing I've found to what I'm trying to achieve is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273788/get-url-variables-from-url-to-form-with-jquery). I'm losing my marbles because I don't understand how the variables are put into the form.

Can someone please break it down / explain?

Here is the form code:

```html
    {% form 'customer_login' %}

      <h1>Login</h1>

      {% include 'form-errors-custom' %}

      <label for="customer_email" class="hidden-label">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="customer_email" placeholder="Email" {% if form.errors contains "email" %} class="error"{% endif %} autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autofocus>

      {% if form.password_needed %}

        <label for="customer_password" class="hidden-label">Password</label>
        <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="customer_password" placeholder="Password" {% if form.errors contains "password" %} class="error"{% endif %}>

        <p>
          <a href="#" onclick="showRecoverPasswordForm();return false;">Forgot your password?</a>
        </p>

      {% endif %}

      <div class="text-center">
        <p>
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In">
        </p>
        or <a href="{{ shop.url }}">Return to Store</a>
      </div>

    {% endform %}
```

Comment: i so no js or jquery here. you may have mis-tagged your question (also in your head)

Comment: See the top answer to this question on how to read url query parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to get the parameters from the URL client side (using JS/Jquery, as per your tags), you can get the query string (using `location.search`) and extract the key/value pairs, then allocate them however you wish.

```js
//var str = location.search

var str = 'customer_email=admin@website.com&customer_password=123456';
var pairs = str.split('&');
var email = pairs[0].split('=')[1];
var password = pairs[1].split('=')[1];
$('#customer_email').val(email);
$('#customer_password').val(password);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="customer_email" placeholder="Email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autofocus>


<input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="customer_password" placeholder="Password" class="error"{% endif %}>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @sideroxylon. I'm a little confused about the div, could you explain? I can't seem to get it populating the form correctly in the email and password fields.

Comment: I've just output the two values so you can see them.  To place them in the form, you'd do something like `$('#customer_email').val(email)` and `$('#customer_password').val(password)`.  This puts the values in the named elements.  I've updated the answer to use your inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, you're fantastic! I've got it working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The parameters that are passed in the url like in your case are like the `get` request and can be received in the same way as you would receive the parameters submitted by the form with `method="get"`. And then you put the variable in the `value` attribute of the form fields in current page.